# Calender with checkbox: How to insert information into database from checkbox

Tags: php

I am trying to create a calender with a checkbox for each date. When a user clicks the submit button, I want to get those selected dates inserted into the database and those which are not selected would be deleted from the database if those already exist before. I have created a index.php page where I wrote the following code to generate dates:

index.php:

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action="show.php">
  <?php
    $year="2011";
    $month="8";
    $d=cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN,1,2011);

    $i=1;
    while($i<=$d)
    {
  ?>
  <input type="checkbox" name="date[]" value="<? echo  " $year-$month- " . $i . ""."<br>";  ?>"> 
  <? echo  " $year-$month- " . $i . ""."<br>";  ?>
  <?
        $i++;
    }

  ?> 
  <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
```

show.php:

```
<? 
    mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die("Could not connect: " . mysql_error()); 
    mysql_select_db("database"); 
    $media_array = $_POST['date']; 
    foreach ($media_array as $one_media) 
    {
        $source .= $one_media.", "; 
    } 
    $media = substr($source, 0, -2); 
    $query = "INSERT INTO table1 (id,media) VALUES('', '$media')";
    $result = mysql_query($query); } 
?>
```

And then I created page another page named show.php where I tried to write codes for inserting information, but I failed.
Would you please kindly help me to do this? I have tried my best but I couldn't make it happened. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show us the show.php page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be to make use of Ajax (going to use the JQuery library to make it a bit easier). So every time a checkbox changes values an Ajax request is triggered to **updateDatabase.php** and it either deletes or inserts a record.

So if you are showing your checkboxes on the page do:

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {

    //Every time a checkbox changes (gets ticked or unticked) send n Ajax request
    //to updateDatabase.php containing its value and a BOOLEAN checked/unchecked
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {
        var checked = $(this).is(':checked'); 
        $.ajax({
             url: "updateDatabase.php",
             type: "POST",
             data: {value : $(this).val(),
                   checked : checked },
             dataType: "html",
             async:false,
             success: function(msg) {
                  //Show the answer from the file in an alertbox.
                  //Use this to debug your code. Leave it out afterwards.
                  alert(msg);
             }
         });
     });

});

</script>
```

So every time a checkbox is checked or unchecked it sends its value and the "checked" boolean value to **updateDatabase.php**.

In this file you can do something similar to:

**updateDatabase.php**

```
<?php
    //Get POST variables
    $value  = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['value']);
    $checked = $_POST['checked'];

    //If the checkbox was checked, INSERT its value into the database
    //else you remove it.
    if ($checked == true) {
        $query  = "INSERT INTO table (value) VALUES ('" . $value . "')";
    }
    else {
        $query = "DELETE FROM table WHERE value = '" . $value . "'";
    }
    mysql_query($query);
?>
```

### EDIT: Added the code to process the data after you click SUBMIT

**If you do not want to do this on the flow**
If you want to update your database when the user clicks SUBMIT, you simply submit the form to **show.php**.

**show.php**

```
<?php
    $dates = $_POST["date"];

    echo "Dates chosen: " . count($dates) . "<br /><br />";

    if (count($dates)>0) {
        echo "You picked the following dates:<br />";
    }

    for ($i=0; $i<count($dates); $i++) {
        echo ($i+1) . ") " . $dates[$i] . "<br />";
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO table (value) VALUES ('" . mysql_real_escape_string($dates[$i]) . "')");
    }
?>
```

Hope this helps you!

(I did not test this code so I'm sorry if there are some minor errors in there still. But I'm sure you catch the drift!)

Comment: Thank You very very much..for your help. I have not tested it yet, but I guess it will work. I will let you know the final result. And again Thanks a lot :)

Comment: You're welcome. If this answer helped you, please tick it as being **correct**. Thanks!

Comment: Thank You very very much again.  It really worked perfectly and exactly the way I wanted. You wrote a code that just worked perfectly but you didn't even have to test it.. YOUR ARE THE BOSS.. :) Actually I cannot thank you enough for this.

Comment: Hi, Jules, its me again. Sorry if I am disturbing you. The code that you wrote previously is working just fine. But now I am facing another problem and that is to populate the dates from database. My aim is when any one visits the page that has the form, I want to have those dates selected which are stored into the database. Would you please kindly help? : For your information, I am using the show.php page to insert the data. :)